# Elasticsearch Aggregation Range Buckets based on characters rather than numbers

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I can get an aggregation of individual text strings with this:

```
       "alpha_titles": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "book_title.keyword",
            "size" : 100,
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
```

But, the requirement I have is to bucket these titles into ranges: A - E, F - J, etc...

the "range" aggregation seems to only work work numeric values.

Is there a way to get buckets of alphabetic strings based on a starting value and ending value - something like a* to e* ???

Comment: I figured it out using the "include" parameter:
```"include" : "[A-E].*",```

Comment: Using these parameters solved your issue? If so, please consider adding it as an answer and accept it :)